# JQuery load needs to update DOM with the new event handlers

Tags: jquery, load

I am well aware JQuery load does not load in scripts but I did not realise it would not load in the event handlers either.

I have a div that is loaded in with a series of elements.

```
<li class="dir" value="53.3301500, -1.5263800">Number 1</li>
<li class="dir" value="53.3298200, -1.5264300">Number 2</li>
```

The following code is in the original file not the one being loaded in ::

```
$('.dir').click(function(){
        alert('blast');
    });
```

So I assumed it would work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When jQuery events are registered, they are registered against the results of the selector when that code is run, so newly generated DOM elements won't have events registered.

Use jQuery's `live()` function to register events for DOM elements that do not yet exist, that will match the selector used: http://api.jquery.com/live/

e.g.

```
$('.dir').live('click', function(){
    alert('blast');
});
```

---

Edit:
From: http://api.jquery.com/live/

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. **Use .on()** to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 2):

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('li.dir').live('click', function() {
    alert('blast not');
});
```

Or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('ul').delegate('li.dir', 'click', function() {
    alert('blast not');
});
```

Delegate is generally faster than a `live` call without context.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything. No idea why. Here is a link. All you need to do is click on directions, enter your postcode and click on one of the loaded in direction http://www.golfbrowser.com/WebObjects/course-pack.html

Comment: I don't see an item in the list with a class of 'dir'.

Comment: When it generates direction after you enter your postcode, each of those directions other than the first and last is structured <li class="dir" .... If you don't know a postcode enter Paris or London